# Determine function is onto or not?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

A function is defined as $$f(x) = \frac{e^{x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2}}$$ f is from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.  check if function is surjective or not,  injective nature of function can be proved easily but i can't think of any way to prove if it is surjective or not. Please help.

Comment: Don't mind my language.

Comment: What do you mean by null?

Comment: I think you read the function wrong, there is a negative sign in 2nd term of numerator and denominator.

Comment: Okk my fault,  sorry.  Can you help?

Comment: Since $$e^{x^2}\ge 1$$ the numerator and denominato are always $\ge 0$.

Comment: Perhaps by "injective nature of the function" you meant "if the function is injective **or** (as it is) **not**".

Comment: I'm saying that I've proved that function is injective but having problem in determining if function is surjective or not.

Comment: The function is not injective, because it is even: $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Comment: I'm asking about surjective.

Comment: Well, sorry. Don't let my comment stop you from believing it is injective, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that
$$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty }f(x)=1.$$
Therefore, it's bounded, and thus not onto.

Comment: Thanks. Will you suggest me some material for "how to determine function is onto or not" i just know to graph the function and see if graph covers whole co-domain or not.

Comment: There is no technic in general. Usually, you take an element $y\in\mathbb R$ and show that there is an $x\in\mathbb R$ s.t. $y=f(x)$. But with continuous function, you can often play with IVT (intermediate value theorem) (what we "very implicitly" used here). And such argue often work.

Comment: Actually I'm still trying to understand, but you help a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if you need more informations to understand better.

Comment: How you use IVT to solve this?

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded, you have that $-M\leq f\leq M$ for a certain $M>0$. Now, since $f$ is continuous, the $IVT$ guarantee you that $f$ take all his value in $[-M,M]$. In other terms, that $\text{Im}(f)\subset [-M,M]$. Therefore, $f(\mathbb R)=\text{Im}(f)\subset [-M,M]\neq \mathbb R$ what prove the claim.

Comment: And how did you conclude that f is bounded. From l'hopital's rule?

Comment: Because $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty }f(x)=1$ and that $f$ is continuous on all $\mathbb R$ (it's easy to prove that if $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and s.t. $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty }f(x)$ exists, then $f$ is bounded).